# Maintain white space when jquery element is not present?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a [gage](http://justgage.com/) that is displayed once data is fetched from a server. The gage is only displayed once the data is received but I am trying to figure out how I can maintain the white space in the html when the gage is not there? At the moment my page jumps up when the gage is not there and pops down once it appears. I really would like it to fade in to I guess. Many thanks.

the html

```
<div id="gauge" class="400x260px"></div>
```

Jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submitButtonId").on("click",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

//Post form 
var formdata = $(this.form).serialize();
    $.post('insert.php', formdata,
           function(data){
  //Reset Form
$('#myform')[0].reset();  
fetchRowCount();
    });

    return false;
 });
});
//Fetch data from server
function fetchRowCount() {
     $.ajax({
                    url: 'server2.php',
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
$("#rows").html(data.rows);
$("#min").html(data.min);
$("#max").html(data.max);
$("#mean").html(data.total);

//Show gage once json is receved from server

           var gage = new JustGage({
          id: "gauge",
          value: data.total,
          min: 1,
          max: 100,
          title: "Sample Data"
       });

                    }
     });

}
</script>
```

Comment: why not put a loader in that place which indicates the data is been loaded.

Comment: try giving CSS min-width and min-height for the gauge div.

Comment: I'm assuming the css class 400x260px has fixed width and height, and display: block? if that is the case, then the space should be reserved unless your JustGage plugin is doing something funky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with css:

```
#gauge {
    height: 260px;
}
```

With jquery:

```
$('#guage').css({'height': '260px'});
```

Css should be the prefered option.

Edit: if the element isn't always that height, you could always use min-height.